# BB10 cascades c , export build release but Bar file is too huge(100mb)!

Tags: build, release, blackberry-10

Firstly, i am sure i have not done something wrong to export build release bar file, for my project. Few weeks ago i have built one release bar for my project, only 1mb.

I did exactly as the following tutorail:
http://bbcascadescode.tumblr.com/post/33340977264/exporting-bar-file-from-cascades-ide

but today when i try to export the release build, the bar file is about 100mb!!!!
There is no problem, no error, but the bar size is abnormal!!!

this is my project's pro file:

```
APP_NAME = myProjectName

CONFIG += qt warn_on debug_and_release cascades mobility

LIBS   += -lbbdata -lbbplatform -lbbcascadesmaps -lbbsystem -lbbutilityi18n -lbbdevice -lz -lbbcascadesmultimedia -lbbpim -lbbmultimedia -lOpenAL -lalut -lasound

MOBILITY += sensors

include(config.pri)

lupdate_inclusion {
    SOURCES += \
        $$BASEDIR/../src/*.cpp \
        $$BASEDIR/../src/control/*.cpp \
        $$BASEDIR/../src/model/*.cpp \
        $$BASEDIR/../src/utils/*.cpp \
        $$BASEDIR/../src/view/*.cpp \
        $$BASEDIR/../assets/items/*.qml \
        $$BASEDIR/../assets/controls/*.qml \
        $$BASEDIR/../assets/*.qml
}

device {
    CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
        DESTDIR = o.le-v7
        #TEMPLATE = lib
        #QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -fvisibility=hidden -mthumb
    }
    CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
        DESTDIR = o.le-v7-g
    }
}

simulator {
    CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
        DESTDIR = o
    }
    CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
        DESTDIR = o-g
    }
}

OBJECTS_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/.obj
MOC_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/.moc
RCC_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/.rcc
UI_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/.ui

suredelete.target = sureclean
suredelete.commands = $(DEL_FILE) $${MOC_DIR}/*; $(DEL_FILE) $${RCC_DIR}/*; $(DEL_FILE) $${UI_DIR}/*
suredelete.depends = distclean

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += suredelete
```

Maybe i import too many libraries?? 
I have no clue till now, because i got no error, just the bar size seems not correct. It can NOT be 100MB. All the source codes and resource files are only 3.3 MB.
Anyone has the same issue?
Thank you for any advice!!

Comment: follow this i have changed the pro file,  https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/getting_started/tools/compiling.html 
 
device {
    CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
        DESTDIR = o.le-v7
        TEMPLATE=lib
        QMAKE_CXX_FLAGS += -fvisible
    }
 
 but it does not help, i found in the compiled bar file, all my source code and resource were packaged inside, this is strange, if i remove those source code and resource, the size is normal

Comment: i found the reason, in bar-descriptor.xml, i add this <asset path="D:/workspace/ndk-workspace/myProjectname">xxxxx</asset>, this is incorrect!!!! and will package all files into the bar